# Python Annotating a histogram but the annotations are not clear

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put labels in my histogram and I did it but the characters in the label are not clear.
My code :

```
x.hist(bsone,bins=200)
for x_label, label in zip(bsone, bsone):
   ax.annotate(x_label, xy=(label, 0), xytext=(label, -20 ))
```

As you can see, the last three digits in the second label are invisible :
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to annotate a lot of points here, which all lie so close to each other that their annotations overlap.

I think you will need to decide how you want the plot to look like and e.g. only annotate two of the points. 
You may e.g. only annotate the first and last point by

```
ax.annotate(bsone[0], xy=(bsone[0], 0), xytext=(bsone[0], -20 ))
ax.annotate(bsone[-1], xy=(bsone[-1], 0), xytext=(bsone[-1], -20 ))
```